# Escaping '<' character in Foundation for Email, Zurb

Tags: html, email, zurb-foundation, html-email, zurb-ink

I'm using https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html to develop my email templates. For each and every template there are parts where I need to add eg. `<%= params.someData %>` but `'<'` gets escaped while compiling, so instead of being `<%= params.someData %>` it generates to `&lt;%= params.firstName %>`

I see that https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html is used for compiling but I'm not able to disabled this functionality in order for < character not to be escaped.

Please help.

Comment: How do you add those `<%= ...>`? Are they directly embedded in the html code?

Comment: @t.niese Yes they are. They are added in html partial file directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the integrated raw helper to do this.

Either use `{{{{raw}}}}...{{{{/raw}}}}` or `<raw>...</raw>`.

Answer (score 1):

In `gulfile.babel.js` use pipe to replace `&lt;%=` with `<%=`. I have had to do this with Adobe Campaign code, which doesn't work well with Zurb Foundation for email.

```
.pipe($.replace, '&lt;%=', `<%=`)
```

Good luck.

Comment: Better use the raw helper ;-)

Comment: @DanielRuf I could never get the raw helper to work with my issues with formatting. Zurb didn't have any solutions. I think there is a known problem. Pipe was the only thing that worked.